# Trouble installing package rms for Rstudio

Tags: r

I have been having an issue installing package rms. I am trying to interpret ordinal models (using the package ordinal) and plot regressions using them. For rms, I don't even get an error, just that it updates other loaded packages, loads and attaches package 'lubridate' which had already been installed, and that 'date' is masked from the base package.

For reference I had originally tried to install hmisc, which I found out was a dependency for rms. This led to an issue installing dependency gfortran. When I attempt to install gfortran, I get

```
  package ‘gfortran’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

But then, when I try to install Hmisc, I get

```
installing the source package ‘Hmisc’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Hmisc_4.4-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 744545 bytes (727 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 727 KB

* installing *source* package ‘Hmisc’ ...
** package ‘Hmisc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c Hmisc.c -o Hmisc.o
gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c cidxcn.f -o cidxcn.o
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [cidxcn.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Hmisc’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Hmisc’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Hmisc’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/5l/r40ht3p511j0mbty0ptcc7zm0000gn/T/RtmpFAI0pw/downloaded_packages’
```

For reference, I run this on a Mac OS Catalina (10.15.4).

Alternatively, if you have any other ways to graph regressions using ordinal models please let me know! Thank you very much.

Comment: That's probably because the latest version of `rms` was built in R 4.0.0 and you need to upgrade R first.

Comment: Thank you for replying - I realized I only upgraded RStudio. Just upgraded R and about to go through and install. Thank you so much - I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Or perhaps the `make: gfortran: No such file or directory` suggests it could not find a compiler, regardless of the versions or R or the package. Perhaps https://mac.r-project.org/tools/ is useful. **Note**: `gfortran` is not an R package, it is something for the operating system on which R depends.

Comment: @markhogue it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: @r2evans, I didn't realize that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error even though I had installed `gfortran` by running `brew install gfortran`. But I needed to add this to my `~/.Rprofile`:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin")
```